# The difference to apply display:flex to the outer container and to the child item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am confused by what the difference is between apply display:flex to a whole container and to an item of that container.

From my experiment, I know that it causes different layout. But why does this cause different layout? And how the different layouts are decided?

if applied to the whole container,
[image]

if applied to subitem in the menu,

[image]

code,

```css
.advanced-nav ul {
  /* display: flex;*/
  /*change me!*/
}

.advanced-nav li a {
  display: flex;
  /*or change me!*/
  width: 100%;
  /* justify-content: flex-start;*/
}
```

```html
<section class="menu-section">
  <h2 class="menu-heading">Advanced Menu</h2>
  <nav id="advanced-nav" class="advanced-nav menu" role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="button-text">
            Home
            <span>is where the heart is</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="button-text">
            Food
            <span>is nourishment for the soul</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="button-text">
            Recipes
            <span>guide you on your journey</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="button-text">
            News
            <span>brings new things</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- #advanced-nav .advanced-nav -->
</section>
<!-- .menu-section -->
```

with code above, although most of css styles are stripped, difference still exists. Any feedback is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: This ***[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)*** can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Add this css

```
.advanced-nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}
.advanced-nav ul li a {
     display: inline-block;
     width: auto;
}

.advanced-nav ul li a .icon {
     display: inline-block;
     width: auto;
}

.advanced-nav ul li a .button-text {
     display: inline-block;
     width: auto;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking for an explanation, not code.